# Docker pull failing after removing user from Gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-registry

Today I was cleaning up old Gitlab accounts for developers who are no longer active. I deleted one account of our first dev who was responsible for all of the initial deployment infra.

We use Docker and Gitlab CI/CD. From what I can understand, we also use Gitlab's package and/or container registries.

I went to deploy a moment ago and pulling seems to be failing:

```
*** System restart required ***
Pulling prerender ... done
Pulling mysql   ... done
Pulling mongo   ... done
Pulling server  ... error
Pulling client  ... error
Pulling nginx   ... done
Pulling redis   ... done
ERROR: for server pull access denied for registry.gitlab.com/foobar/repo-1, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
ERROR: for client pull access denied for registry.gitlab.com/foobar/repo-2, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
ERROR: pull access denied for registry.gitlab.com/foobar/repo-2, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I'm not that familiar with Docker and Gitlab's CI/CD/Registries features. Any suggestions for where to begin looking to get things back on track would be appreciated!

Comment: When you removed the account, is it possible you may have also [removed their contributions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/account/delete_account.html#delete-users-and-user-contributions) and associated data? If the user was the sole owner of that project or group, you may have accidentally deleted the repo along with the group/project. Is this a self-hosted instance? It looks like you're being denied access to a `gitlab.com` registry: "denied for registry.gitlab.com"

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that CI was using that user to get docker images from the gitlab registry.

In order to fix this, I:

1. Created a dummy gitlab user (@company-bot) and invited that account to our team
2. Created a personal token on that user
3. Logged in to our production instance and issued the following command:

- `docker login registry.gitlab.com/company/repo1 -u company-bot -p personal-token`
- `docker login registry.gitlab.com/company/repo2 -u company-bot -p personal-token`

This way, the login credentials aren't stored against an actual user, so removing users in the future should be safe.

Comment: Under which user did you run the `docker login` command?